# WASSessionCor W SessionAffinityManager setCookie SESN0066E: The response is already committed to the client. The session cookie cannot be set

Tags: websphere, cxf

*WASSessionCor W SessionAffinityManager setCookie SESN0066E: The response is already committed to the client. The session cookie cannot be set.*

I am getting the above error whenever web services in my web application are accessed.
The web services and application server that I am using are:
CXF 2.6.14, spring 4.1 and WebSphere 8.5.5

** NOTE**: The WARNING messages stopped when I disabled the session cookies setting at EAR level wherever web services are installed and by skipping at WAR level where the console app is deployed. **But I need a actual permanent solution as disabling cookies is against security policies**.

```
        Line 478056: [9/5/17 13:36:38:597 EDT] 000001e9 util          1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.EventListeners fireEvent Use visitor com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.FireOnServletFinishService@2c012c01 to fire event to com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebAppPmiListener@5a435a43, class:class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebAppPmiListener
Line 478062: [9/5/17 13:36:38:598 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getAttribute this->com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest@1bcf1bcf:  name --> javax.servlet.include.request_uri
Line 478065: [9/5/17 13:36:38:598 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getRequestURI  uri --> /workflowWeb/WorkflowStatisticService
Line 478080: [9/5/17 13:36:38:598 EDT] 000001e9 stats         1 com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.stats.WebAppModule onServletFinishService pmi WebAppModule received onServletFinishService for servlet:CXFServlet, url:/workflowWeb/WorkflowStatisticService
Line 478086: [9/5/17 13:36:38:598 EDT] 000001e9 stats         1 com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.stats.ServletPmiModule decRequests decrementing requests for the servlet:CXFServlet, url:/workflowWeb/WorkflowStatisticService, execTime=349
Line 478090: [9/5/17 13:36:38:598 EDT] 000001e9 PmiCollaborat >  getInstrumentationLevel (StatDescriptor, Boolean) Entry
Line 478097: [9/5/17 13:36:38:599 EDT] 000001e9 PmiCollaborat <  getInstrumentationLevel (StatDescriptor, Boolean) Exit
Line 478103: [9/5/17 13:36:38:599 EDT] 000001e9 ServletWrappe < com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service  RETURN  className-->[org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet] ,request-> [org.springframework.security.wrapper.SavedRequestAwareWrapper@66536653] ,response->[org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter$OnRedirectUpdateSessionResponseWrapper@6ee96ee9
Line 478106: [9/5/17 13:36:38:599 EDT] 000001e9 filter        < com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain doFilter RETURN
Line 478223: [9/5/17 13:36:38:600 EDT] 000001e9 BNFHeadersImp 3   getHeaderAsString(h): $WSRA [192.168.76.9]
Line 478248: [9/5/17 13:36:38:601 EDT] 000001e9 WCCRequestImp 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCRequestImpl getRemoteAddr  isTrusted --> true addr --> 192.168.76.9
Line 478278: [9/5/17 13:36:38:601 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getRemoteAddr this->com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest@1bcf1bcf:  address --> 192.168.76.9
Line 478291: [9/5/17 13:36:38:601 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getSession create false
Line 478295: [9/5/17 13:36:38:601 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor > SessionContext getIHttpSession ENTRY createIfAbsent = false
Line 478323: [9/5/17 13:36:38:602 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getSessionAffinityContext  sac --> {JSESSIONID/=# SessionAffinityContext # 
Line 478379: [9/5/17 13:36:38:602 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 SessionContext getSessionAffinityContext Found sac on request for key JSESSIONID/
Line 478391: [9/5/17 13:36:38:602 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor < SessionContext getIHttpSession RETURN
Line 478397: [9/5/17 13:36:38:602 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest removeAttribute this->com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest@1bcf1bcf:  name --> __spring_security_session_integration_filter_applied
Line 478406: [9/5/17 13:36:38:602 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest attributeRemoved this->com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest@1bcf1bcf:  key --> __spring_security_session_integration_filter_applied value --> true
Line 478414: [9/5/17 13:36:38:603 EDT] 000001e9 collaborator  > com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppNameSpaceCollaboratorImpl preInvoke ENTRY MetaDataImpl@301142515
Line 478419: [9/5/17 13:36:38:603 EDT] 000001e9 collaborator  < com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppNameSpaceCollaboratorImpl preInvoke RETURN
Line 478424: [9/5/17 13:36:38:603 EDT] 000001e9 collaborator  > com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppNameSpaceCollaboratorImpl postInvoke ENTRY
Line 478428: [9/5/17 13:36:38:603 EDT] 000001e9 collaborator  < com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppNameSpaceCollaboratorImpl postInvoke RETURN
Line 478431: [9/5/17 13:36:38:603 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getSession create false
Line 478432: [9/5/17 13:36:38:603 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor > SessionContext getIHttpSession ENTRY createIfAbsent = false
Line 478514: [9/5/17 13:36:38:603 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getSessionAffinityContext  sac --> {JSESSIONID/=# SessionAffinityContext # 
Line 478532: [9/5/17 13:36:38:605 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 SessionContext getSessionAffinityContext Found sac on request for key JSESSIONID/
Line 478534: [9/5/17 13:36:38:605 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor < SessionContext getIHttpSession RETURN
Line 478537: [9/5/17 13:36:38:605 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getSession create true
Line 478540: [9/5/17 13:36:38:605 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor > SessionContext getIHttpSession ENTRY createIfAbsent = true
Line 478544: [9/5/17 13:36:38:605 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getSessionAffinityContext  sac --> {JSESSIONID/=# SessionAffinityContext # 
Line 478560: [9/5/17 13:36:38:605 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 SessionContext getSessionAffinityContext Found sac on request for key JSESSIONID/
Line 478562: [9/5/17 13:36:38:605 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor > SessionManager createISession ENTRY id= null
Line 478638: [9/5/17 13:36:38:605 EDT] 000001e9 util          1 IDGeneratorImpl getSessionID sessionID=GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6
Line 478641: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor > MemoryStore createSession ENTRY {GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6,true} 
Line 478644: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor > SessionSimpleHashMap get ENTRY GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6
Line 478646: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor < SessionSimpleHashMap get RETURN key not found
Line 478649: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 MemorySession setUserName New Value=anonymous; Old Value=null AppName=default_hostworkflowWeb; Id=GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6
Line 478650: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 MemorySession getCreationTime 1504632998607 AppName=default_hostworkflowWeb; Id=GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6
Line 478651: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 MemorySession updateLastAccessTime 1504632998607
Line 478676: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor > SessionSimpleHashMap put ENTRY {GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6} 
Line 478677: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 SessionEventDispatcher sessionLiveCountInc sessionObservers.size()=2
Line 478678: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 ServletSessio 3   sessionAdded
Line 478679: [9/5/17 13:36:38:607 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor < SessionSimpleHashMap put RETURN add new entry to Hashmap
Line 478680: [9/5/17 13:36:38:608 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor < MemoryStore createSession RETURN # com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession # 
Line 478711: [9/5/17 13:36:38:608 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 MemorySession incrementRefCount to 1 from 0 AppName=default_hostworkflowWeb; Id=GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6
Line 478715: [9/5/17 13:36:38:608 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 MemorySession setMaxInactiveInterval New Value=1800; Old Value=0 AppName=default_hostworkflowWeb; Id=GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6
Line 478718: [9/5/17 13:36:38:608 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 SessionEventDispatcher sessionCreated sessionObservers.size()=2
Line 478804: [9/5/17 13:36:38:608 EDT] 000001e9 WASSession    1 returnFacade returnFacade: cea not installed  returning WsHttpSessionFacade
Line 478831: [9/5/17 13:36:38:609 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor < SessionManager createISession RETURN
Line 478837: [9/5/17 13:36:38:609 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 MemorySession getVersion() 0 AppName=default_hostworkflowWeb; Id=GrLidsIlyFyccNghdnDjfV6
Line 478861: [9/5/17 13:36:38:609 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor > SessionAffinityManager setCookie ENTRY
Line 478865: [9/5/17 13:36:38:609 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 SessionAffinityManager updateCloneInfo Setting cloneID::18p1a5v9n:
Line 478872: [9/5/17 13:36:38:609 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor 1 SessionAffinityManager setCookie Setting cookie: JSESSIONID;Path: /;Comment: SessionManagement;MaxAge: -1;Secure: false
Line 478875: [9/5/17 13:36:38:609 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletRes 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse isCommitted headersWritten=true [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse@1ee81ee8]
Line 478892: [9/5/17 13:36:38:609 EDT] 000001e9 WASSessionCor W SessionAffinityManager setCookie SESN0066E: The response is already committed to the client. The session cookie cannot be set.
Line 478910: [9/5/17 13:36:38:610 EDT] 000001e9 MBeanServerDe >  handleNotification Entry
Line 478915: [9/5/17 13:36:38:610 EDT] 000001e9 WsNotifDelega 3   Delegating notif javax.management.Notification[source=WebSphere:name=RasLoggingService,process=JVM1,platform=proxy,node=rbc-WMSNode01,version=7.0.0.29,type=RasLoggingService,mbeanIdentifier=cells/rbc-WMSCell01/nodes/rbc-WMSNode01/servers/JVM1/server.xml#RASLoggingService_1401277316952,cell=rbc-WMSCell01,spec=1.0][type=websphere.ras.warning][message=] to NotificationService
Line 478918: [9/5/17 13:36:38:610 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationS >  handleNotification Entry
Line 478928: [9/5/17 13:36:38:610 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   NotificationDispatcher: (ndID=6801)
Line 478940: [9/5/17 13:36:38:610 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6801): Emitting to 2 listeners: javax.management.Notification[source=WebSphere:name=RasLoggingService,process=JVM1,platform=proxy,node=rbc-WMSNode01,version=7.0.0.29,type=RasLoggingService,mbeanIdentifier=cells/rbc-WMSCell01/nodes/rbc-WMSNode01/servers/JVM1/server.xml#RASLoggingService_1401277316952,cell=rbc-WMSCell01,spec=1.0][type=websphere.ras.warning][message=] AdminContext:null
Line 478942: [9/5/17 13:36:38:611 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6801): 0: LocalNotificationService@636560881
Line 478995: [9/5/17 13:36:38:611 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6801): 1: com.ibm.ws.management.event.PushRemoteSender: [listenerId=1504623929869; filter=ConsolidatedFilter: [FilterElement:[id=1102791099;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:type=WebModule,name=wasportlet.war,J2EEApplication=isclite,*;filter=javax.management.NotificationFilterSupport@34d334d3]], FilterElement:[id=708061748;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:process=nodeagent,type=Server,processType=NodeAgent,*;filter=javax.management.NotificationFilterSupport@1f4f1f4f]], FilterElement:[id=773533211;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:type=Server,processType=NodeAgent,*;filter=javax.management.NotificationFilterSupport@33133313]], FilterElement:[id=64291797;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:type=StatusCache,node=rbc-WMSNode01,process=nodeagent,*;filter=null]], FilterElement:[id=416356561;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:type=Server,process=JVM1,*;filter=javax.management.NotificationFilterSupport@37703770]], Fi...
Line 479015: [9/5/17 13:36:38:611 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6801): Listener #0 is enabled
Line 479035: [9/5/17 13:36:38:611 EDT] 000001e9 ConsolidatedF >  isNotificationEnabled Entry
Line 479060: [9/5/17 13:36:38:612 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 479063: [9/5/17 13:36:38:612 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 479067: [9/5/17 13:36:38:612 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 479077: [9/5/17 13:36:38:612 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 479866: [9/5/17 13:36:38:618 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 479869: [9/5/17 13:36:38:618 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 479875: [9/5/17 13:36:38:618 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 479881: [9/5/17 13:36:38:618 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 479891: [9/5/17 13:36:38:618 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480007: [9/5/17 13:36:38:618 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480011: [9/5/17 13:36:38:620 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480013: [9/5/17 13:36:38:620 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480016: [9/5/17 13:36:38:620 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480020: [9/5/17 13:36:38:620 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480024: [9/5/17 13:36:38:620 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480028: [9/5/17 13:36:38:620 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480035: [9/5/17 13:36:38:621 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480039: [9/5/17 13:36:38:621 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480058: [9/5/17 13:36:38:621 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480065: [9/5/17 13:36:38:621 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480068: [9/5/17 13:36:38:621 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480086: [9/5/17 13:36:38:621 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480090: [9/5/17 13:36:38:621 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480095: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480101: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480107: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480111: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480117: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480119: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480121: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480123: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480125: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480128: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480135: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480141: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480150: [9/5/17 13:36:38:622 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480168: [9/5/17 13:36:38:623 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480176: [9/5/17 13:36:38:623 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480241: [9/5/17 13:36:38:623 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480243: [9/5/17 13:36:38:624 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI >  containsName Entry
Line 480254: [9/5/17 13:36:38:624 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI 3   current name:
Line 480258: [9/5/17 13:36:38:624 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationI <  containsName Exit
Line 480262: [9/5/17 13:36:38:624 EDT] 000001e9 ConsolidatedF <  isNotificationEnabled Exit
Line 480271: [9/5/17 13:36:38:624 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6801): Listener #1 is enabled
Line 480315: [9/5/17 13:36:38:624 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6801): Dispatched to 2 listeners
Line 480322: [9/5/17 13:36:38:624 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationS <  handleNotification Exit
Line 480338: [9/5/17 13:36:38:624 EDT] 000001e9 MBeanServerDe <  handleNotification Exit
Line 480345: [9/5/17 13:36:38:625 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletRes > com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addSessionCookie ENTRY cookie --> JSESSIONID [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse@1ee81ee8]
Line 480351: [9/5/17 13:36:38:625 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletRes 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse isCommitted headersWritten=true [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse@1ee81ee8]
Line 480353: [9/5/17 13:36:38:625 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletRes 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse getRequest request=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest@1bcf1bcf [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse@1ee81ee8]
Line 480356: [9/5/17 13:36:38:625 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletReq 1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest getWebAppDispatcherContext 
Line 480375: [9/5/17 13:36:38:625 EDT] 000001e9 SRTServletRes W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addSessionCookie WARNING: Cannot set session cookie. Response already committed.
Line 480418: [9/5/17 13:36:38:625 EDT] 000001e9 MBeanServerDe >  handleNotification Entry
Line 480426: [9/5/17 13:36:38:626 EDT] 000001e9 WsNotifDelega 3   Delegating notif javax.management.Notification[source=WebSphere:name=RasLoggingService,process=JVM1,platform=proxy,node=rbc-WMSNode01,version=7.0.0.29,type=RasLoggingService,mbeanIdentifier=cells/rbc-WMSCell01/nodes/rbc-WMSNode01/servers/JVM1/server.xml#RASLoggingService_1401277316952,cell=rbc-WMSCell01,spec=1.0][type=websphere.ras.warning][message=] to NotificationService
Line 480429: [9/5/17 13:36:38:626 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationS >  handleNotification Entry
Line 480438: [9/5/17 13:36:38:626 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   NotificationDispatcher: (ndID=6803)
Line 480445: [9/5/17 13:36:38:626 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6803): Emitting to 2 listeners: javax.management.Notification[source=WebSphere:name=RasLoggingService,process=JVM1,platform=proxy,node=rbc-WMSNode01,version=7.0.0.29,type=RasLoggingService,mbeanIdentifier=cells/rbc-WMSCell01/nodes/rbc-WMSNode01/servers/JVM1/server.xml#RASLoggingService_1401277316952,cell=rbc-WMSCell01,spec=1.0][type=websphere.ras.warning][message=] AdminContext:null
Line 480448: [9/5/17 13:36:38:626 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6803): 0: LocalNotificationService@636560881
Line 480461: [9/5/17 13:36:38:626 EDT] 000001e9 NotificationD 3   (ndID=6803): 1: com.ibm.ws.management.event.PushRemoteSender: [listenerId=1504623929869; filter=ConsolidatedFilter: [FilterElement:[id=1102791099;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:type=WebModule,name=wasportlet.war,J2EEApplication=isclite,*;filter=javax.management.NotificationFilterSupport@34d334d3]], FilterElement:[id=708061748;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:process=nodeagent,type=Server,processType=NodeAgent,*;filter=javax.management.NotificationFilterSupport@1f4f1f4f]], FilterElement:[id=773533211;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:type=Server,processType=NodeAgent,*;filter=javax.management.NotificationFilterSupport@33133313]], FilterElement:[id=64291797;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:type=StatusCache,node=rbc-WMSNode01,process=nodeagent,*;filter=null]], FilterElement:[id=416356561;info=NotificationInfo: [name=WebSphere:type=Server,process=JVM1,*;filter=javax.management.NotificationFilterSupport@37703770]], Fi...
```

Comment: suppressing WARNING in websphere server is one workaround I can think of currently